# Infinity norm of matrix as inequality constraint in optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, control-theory, linear-matrix-inequality

Imagine the optimization problem below, where the matrix $\ell_\infty$ norm appears as an inequality constraint:

\begin{equation}
\min_{X} \| XB - C\|_F^2 \\ \text{s.t. } \|AXB - B\|_\infty \leqslant t,
\end{equation}

where $A_{L \times N}$, $B_{L \times M}$, $C_{N \times M}$ with $L > N$ are given, $t$ is a given threshold, and $X_{N \times L}$ is the optimization variable. We also define the $\ell_{\infty}$ of the matrix as maximum of the absolute values of the matrix elements.

Defining $T_{L \times M}$ as a matrix whose all elements equal $t$, one can write the $\ell_{\infty}$ constraint in matrix inequality constraint as $-T \leqslant AXB - B \leqslant +T$, where the inequality is element-wise. However, since the matrices are non-square, I am not sure how to get rid of $A$ and $B$. Furthermore, the matrix multiplication in $AXB$ is performed from both sides.

Can this $\ell_{\infty}$ inequality constraint, or equivalently the matrix linear inequality constraint be written in some standard form? I have seen similar forms in control theory but they were talking about square matrices.

Does it help to have some structure in the matrices? For example, I know that $B$ is additionally sparse.

Comment: I wonder if your first line was intended to say $\displaystyle \min_X \|XB - C\|_F^2.$ If so, you can write it that way. $\qquad$

Comment: Did you mean $\le t$ perhaps?

Comment: What's bilinear about this?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I thought $AXB$ is bilinear since it's a multiplication from both sides, as opposed to $AX$ or $XB$. Am I wrong with this terminology?

Comment: @Sohrab Both $A$ and $B$ are given, right? When I read "bilinear", I think of $c_{ij} x_i y_j$.

Comment: @copper.hat Actually not. Since the construction of the problem requires that the $\ell_{\infty}$ be exactly equal to $t$, as set by the system design.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes $A$ and $B$ are both given. So please let me know if I was wrong, so that I edit the post accordingly. Do you know how to name it otherwise?

Comment: @Sohrab I would call it "linear". Also, this is not a convex problem.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, modified the "bilinear" to "linear". For the issue about convexity, I was hoping that some modifications, like e.g., writing it as a one-sided multiplication would make it convex, so tagged it as convex-optimization. Just to make sure, it is the two-sided-ness of $AXB$ that makes it non-convex, right?

Comment: @Sohrab The feasible region is non-convex because it is the boundary of a polytope. If you had $\leq t$ it would be convex.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Oh, then know I see why copper.hat commented so. I am going to update the question to $\leqslant$, since I'd be equally interested in both problems, but prefer it to be convex.

Comment: @Sohrab the two-sided multiplication doesn't change the fact that it's linear.  After all, if you double $X$, you double $AXB$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Now I see. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelGrant I get my desired answer using CVX, however for very tiny scales, i.e., $M, N \& L \simeq$  couple of tens and near 2 hrs of processing on a good machine with massive RAM over-load. This is all because of  the $AXB$ term, which hinders me to target the actual scales of the problem. Any immediate way to reformulate $AXB$ in CVX to speed-up the solution?